# Highcharts Example Modification

Tags: javascript, highcharts, lines

Below is a link to the Highcharts example I want to modify. I would like to have the right 2 y-Axes become one. Currently, each line on the graph corresponds with one y-Axis because they have different scales. The chart I want to create will have 1 right Axis, but correspond to the lowest and highest extreme of both lines in the chart. For example, if line A has low value of 5(and is lower than any value in B line), and line B has an extreme value of 90(and is higher than any value in A), these 2 values are used for the axes. The two lines on the chart should correspond to one scale.

Link: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

Curernt code:

```
var chart;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Example 1'
                    },
                    xAxis: [{
                        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                    }],
                    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.value +'%';
                            },
                            style: {
                                color: '#89A54E'
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Percent Change',
                            style: {
                                color: '#89A54E'
                            }
                        },
                        opposite: true

                    }, { // Secondary yAxis
                        gridLineWidth: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Measure',
                            style: {
                                color: '#4572A7'
                            }
                        },
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.value + 'k';
                            },
                            style: {
                                color: '#4572A7'
                            }
                        }
                    }, { // Tertiary yAxis
                        gridLineWidth: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: '',
                            style: {
                                color: '#AA4643'
                            }
                        },
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.value +' %';
                            },
                            style: {
                                color: '#AA4643'
                            }
                        },
                        opposite: true
                    }],

                series: [{
                    name: 'Measures',  //Button on Graph -- Measures
                    color: '#363534',
                    type: 'column',
                    yAxis: 1,
                    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            }, {
                    name: 'Percentage Change 1', //Button on Graph -- Purple
                    type: 'spline',
                    color: '#E17000',
                    yAxis: 2,
                    data: [30,40,35,25,14,25,39,28,21,78,23,36,5],
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
            },
                    dashStyle: 'shortdot'
            }, {
                     name: 'Percentage Change 2', //Button on Graph -- Orange
                     color: '#A31A7E',
                     type: 'spline',
                     data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 35],
            }]
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, perhaps consider another way of representing the data. The multiple scales can be a mental strain.
2. Second, maybe this helps? I've removed the `$(document).ready...` wrapper.

   ```
             var chart;

           chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
               chart: {
                   renderTo: 'container',
               },
               title: {
                   text: 'Example 1'
               },
               xAxis: [{
                   categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                       'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
               }],
               yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                   labels: {
                       formatter: function() {
                           return this.value +'%';
                       },
                       style: {
                           color: '#878787'
                       }
                   },
                   title: {
                       text: 'Percent Change',
                       style: {
                           color: '#878787'
                       }
                   },
                   opposite: true

               }, { // Secondary yAxis
                   gridLineWidth: 0,
                   title: {
                       text: 'Measure',
                       style: {
                           color: '#4572A7'
                       }
                   },
                   labels: {
                       formatter: function() {
                           return this.value + 'k';
                       },
                       style: {
                           color: '#4572A7'
                       }
                   }
               }],
           series: [{
               name: 'Measures',  //Button on Graph -- Measures
               color: '#363534',
               type: 'column',
               yAxis: 1,
               data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
       }, {
               name: 'Percentage Change 1', //Button on Graph -- Purple
               type: 'spline',
               color: '#E17000',
               data: [30,40,35,25,14,25,39,28,21,78,23,36,5],
               marker: {
                   enabled: false
       },
               dashStyle: 'shortdot'
       }, {
                name: 'Percentage Change 2', //Button on Graph -- Orange
                color: '#A31A7E',
           type: 'spline',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 35],
   }]  });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to set yAxis property for series array. Make yAxis: 0 for both series objects. This should give a single Y axis regardless of number of series items on the chart.